# How can I prove whether a char in a string is equal to a specific char?

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, character

I would like to prove whether the first character in my string is equal to "@". How can I do this? I'm using c#

```
if (string[1] == "<character>")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
                    }
```

Comment: Strings are indexed from 0 not from 1, so it would be `if (string[0] == '@') ...`

Comment: You're code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @MiGro Syntax error at 10: "Your" ;D

Comment: `string` is not the ideal name for a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var s = "@";
    if (s[0] == '@')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StartsWith`:

```
if (str.StartsWith("@"))
{
     Console.Writeline("TRUE");
}
```

If the variable you are testing could be null you can handle that using:

```
if (str?.StartsWith("@") ?? false)
{
     Console.Writeline("TRUE");
}
```

Comment: @HariHaran Why would that be? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to

Comment: I'd add a null-Check on `str`.

Comment: @Fildor oops sorry, i was'nt aware

Answer (score 0):

```
if (someString[0] == '@')
{
    Console.Writeline("TRUE");
}
```

1. Do not use 'string' as variable name.
2. First character of a string has index = 0.
3. For char value use '@', not "@".

Answer (score -1):

You can get an specific char from a string using substring:

```
 char firstCharacter = string.Substring(0,1).ToCharArray()[0];

 if (firstCharacter == '@')
 {
     Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
 }
```

First number in substring function is the first character you will recover (by the way, characters in a string are counted from 0, so first character will be the character "0"). Second number is how many characters you want to retrieve (in your case only one).

The strange part is toCharArray. Substring function returns a string that you want to compare to a char. So you need to convert string to a char array, the get first element of that array, and compare that to your char.

EDIT: some people answered using StartsWith function. This also work, but in case you want other character other than first one, it may be useful to know this approach. But if you don't understand this, go with StartsWith.

Comment: Yes, some capital letters in the name of functions are missing

Comment: ... and you cannot use `string` like is done here. Also some more issues: What if string is null? What if string is empty? You'll have to check all that explicitly.